# Really odd behavior in my ping command

Tags: networking, server, dns, malware, ping

I was experimenting with echoing `$?` for error codes so I was trying to test successful pings and ping timeouts and non-existent host names, etc.

I tried `ping -c 1 lkmdsalkmsalkmdaklsldm.com` to give it a completely nonsense host.

And yet no matter what nonsense I put there it always seemed to try to contact a specific IP, `92.242.140.21`.

I tried `host 92.242.140.21` and it resolves to `unallocated.barefruit.co.uk`.

Needless to say I find this extremely bizarre. Am I finding evidence of malware here? Or a hack? Why is my system trying to contact some site in the UK when I feed my ping command a nonexistent site?

Comment: what DNS are you using; standard traceroute|whois|.. provided nothing to me for that IP; so I'd suspect your DNS is changing non-existent first, before you blame your OS.

Comment: I am not sure how to check my DNS

Comment: use `nmcli device show enp0s25 | grep IP4.DNS`  (where enp0s25 is replaced by your ethernet port name; enp0s25 was mine!) to view what DNS (domain name service) is used.  I assume you get the details from DHCP when you get IP.  try switching it to 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS) for awhile and see if you get the same result. if you do [same problem with google DNS] the issue is your system, but if not your DNS is doing funny things.  edit: use IP4 (not IP4.DNS) if running 14.04 LTS

Comment: How do you get your ethernet port name?

Comment: the modern way is `ip addr`, but my fingers still use `ifconfig`  (interface config)

Comment: @chrisguiver Ok I think I got it. I did that command and got two IP addresses. First was the IP of my router, second is an IP which, according to Google, is a DNS server of my ISP